# JavaScript for loop will not sort out information by state

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I am writing an HTML to display the name of all 50 states and it will show a candidate ids next to the states to show who contributed to campaigns for the state.

I have a JSON of results, which can be found here (don't worry I will use another API key) for the sake of neatness: https://api.open.fec.gov/v1/presidential/contributions/by_state/?sort_nulls_last=false&sort=-contribution_receipt_amount&per_page=20&sort_null_only=false&sort_hide_null=false&page=1&api_key=r6K96zZiE3CiSz10AhkCh0EGSpKNbxmDYD4osUAN
I will be using the results portion of the JSON (converted to array).

I want to be able to use JavaScript for loops so that I can sort the candidate id by state, but my html page is printing out the candidate id in every line of the results and it is doing that for all 50 states. What is wrong with my code?

In my code, please note those are not the entire documents, just the snippets I need to know about.

```js
let carweekstates = {
  'AK': 'alaska',
  'AL': 'alabama',
  'AR': 'arkansas',
  'AZ': 'arizona',
  'CA': 'california',
  'CO': 'colorado',
  'CT': 'connecticut',
  'DE': 'delaware',
  'FL': 'florida',
  'GA': 'georgia',
  'HI': 'hawaii',
  'IA': 'iowa',
  'ID': 'idaho',
  'IL': 'illinois',
  'IN': 'indiana',
  'KS': 'kansas',
  'KY': 'kentucky',
  'LA': 'louisiana',
  'MA': 'massachusetts',
  'MD': 'maryland',
  'ME': 'maine',
  'MI': 'michigan',
  'MN': 'minnesota',
  'MO': 'missouri',
  'MS': 'mississippi',
  'MT': 'montana',
  'NC': 'northcarolina',
  'ND': 'northdakota',
  'NE': 'nebraska',
  'NH': 'newhampshire',
  'NJ': 'newjersey',
  'NM': 'newmexico',
  'NV': 'nevada',
  'NY': 'newyork',
  'OH': 'ohio',
  'OK': 'oklahoma',
  'OR': 'oregon',
  'PA': 'pennsylvania',
  'RI': 'rhodeisland',
  'SC': 'southcarolina',
  'SD': 'southdakota',
  'TN': 'tennessee',
  'TX': 'texas',
  'UT': 'utah',
  'VA': 'virginia',
  'VT': 'vermont',
  'WA': 'washington',
  'WI': 'wisconsin',
  'WV': 'westvirginia',
  'WY': 'wyoming',
}

var jsonOfResults = '{"api_version":"1.0","pagination":{"page":1,"pages":145,"per_page":20,"count":2888},"results":[{"contribution_receipt_amount":152306310.0,"election_year":2016,"candidate_id":"P00000001","contribution_state":"CA"},{"contribution_receipt_amount":114485560.0,"election_year":2016,"candidate_id":"P00000002","contribution_state":"CA"},{"contribution_receipt_amount":101453159.0,"election_year":2020,"candidate_id":"P00000001","contribution_state":"CA"},{"contribution_receipt_amount":93681171.0,"election_year":2016,"candidate_id":"P00003392","contribution_state":"CA"},{"contribution_receipt_amount":91292718.0,"election_year":2016,"candidate_id":"P00000001","contribution_state":"NY"},{"contribution_receipt_amount":83166303.0,"election_year":2020,"candidate_id":"P00000002","contribution_state":"CA"},{"contribution_receipt_amount":75857465.0,"election_year":2016,"candidate_id":"P00000001","contribution_state":"TX"},{"contribution_receipt_amount":73221182.0,"election_year":2016,"candidate_id":"P00000002","contribution_state":"NY"},{"contribution_receipt_amount":64565396.0,"election_year":2016,"candidate_id":"P00003392","contribution_state":"NY"},{"contribution_receipt_amount":58095188.0,"election_year":2016,"candidate_id":"P00000001","contribution_state":"FL"},{"contribution_receipt_amount":53329034.0,"election_year":2020,"candidate_id":"P00000001","contribution_state":"NY"},{"contribution_receipt_amount":49070876.0,"election_year":2016,"candidate_id":"P00000003","contribution_state":"TX"},{"contribution_receipt_amount":46239554.0,"election_year":2020,"candidate_id":"P00000002","contribution_state":"NY"},{"contribution_receipt_amount":36885690.0,"election_year":2020,"candidate_id":"P00000001","contribution_state":"TX"},{"contribution_receipt_amount":36453786.0,"election_year":2016,"candidate_id":"P00000003","contribution_state":"CA"},{"contribution_receipt_amount":32225392.0,"election_year":2016,"candidate_id":"P00000003","contribution_state":"FL"},{"contribution_receipt_amount":31390178.0,"election_year":2016,"candidate_id":"P00000001","contribution_state":"MA"},{"contribution_receipt_amount":29632239.0,"election_year":2020,"candidate_id":"P00000001","contribution_state":"FL"},{"contribution_receipt_amount":28630861.0,"election_year":2016,"candidate_id":"P00000001","contribution_state":"VA"},{"contribution_receipt_amount":28438374.0,"election_year":2016,"candidate_id":"P00000001","contribution_state":"IL"}]}'



var obj = JSON.parse(jsonOfResults);

for (i = 0; i < obj.results.length; i++) {
  for (let states in carweekstates) {

    if (obj.results[i].contribution_state = states) {
      document.getElementById("to-" + carweekstates[states]).innerHTML += obj.results[i].candidate_id + "; ";


    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="to-alaska">Alaska: </div>
<div id="to-alabama">Alabama: </div>
<div id="to-arkansas">Arkansas: </div>
<div id="to-arizona">Arizona: </div>
<div id="to-california">California: </div>
<div id="to-colorado">Colorado: </div>
<div id="to-connecticut">Connecticut: </div>
<div id="to-delaware">Delaware: </div>
<div id="to-florida">Florida: </div>
<div id="to-georgia">Georgia: </div>
<div id="to-hawaii">Hawaii: </div>
<div id="to-iowa">Iowa: </div>
<div id="to-idaho">Idaho: </div>
<div id="to-illinois">Illinois: </div>
<div id="to-indiana">Indiana: </div>
<div id="to-kansas">Kansas: </div>
<div id="to-kentucky">Kentucky: </div>
<div id="to-louisiana">Louisiana: </div>
<div id="to-massachusetts">Massachusetts: </div>
<div id="to-maryland">Maryland: </div>
<div id="to-maine">Maine: </div>
<div id="to-michigan">Michigan: </div>
<div id="to-minnesota">Minnesota: </div>
<div id="to-missouri">Missouri: </div>
<div id="to-mississippi">Mississippi: </div>
<div id="to-montana">Montana: </div>
<div id="to-northcarolina">North Carolina: </div>
<div id="to-northdakota">North Dakota: </div>
<div id="to-nebraska">Nebraska: </div>
<div id="to-newhampshire">New Hampshire: </div>
<div id="to-newjersey">New Jersey: </div>
<div id="to-newmexico">New Mexico: </div>
<div id="to-nevada">Nevada: </div>
<div id="to-newyork">New York: </div>
<div id="to-ohio">Ohio: </div>
<div id="to-oklahoma">Oklahoma: </div>
<div id="to-oregon">Oregon: </div>
<div id="to-pennsylvania">Pennsylvania: </div>
<div id="to-rhodeisland">Rhode Island: </div>
<div id="to-southcarolina">South Carolina: </div>
<div id="to-southdakota">South Dakota: </div>
<div id="to-tennessee">Tennessee: </div>
<div id="to-texas">Texas: </div>
<div id="to-utah">Utah: </div>
<div id="to-virginia">Virginia: </div>
<div id="to-vermont">Vermont: </div>
<div id="to-washington">Washington: </div>
<div id="to-wisconsin">Wisconsin: </div>
<div id="to-westvirginia">West Virginia: </div>
<div id="to-wyoming">Wyoming: </div>
```

For example, California should show: `California: P00000001; P00000002; P00000001; P00003392; P00000002;P00000003` based on the JSON data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `=` is used for setting the left hand side to the right hand side. `==` and `===` are used for comparing the left hand side to the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your issue I managed to create this fix. Hope it suits your case

```
let obj = JSON.parse(jsonOfResults);
for(let state in carweekstates) {
    let out = carweekstates[state] + " ";
    for(let i = 0 ; i < obj.results.length ; i++) {
        let contributionState = obj.results[i];
        if(contributionState.contribution_state === state) {
            out += contributionState.candidate_id  + "; "
        }
    }
    console.log(out);
}
```

I got this output for California:

```
california P00000001; P00000002; P00000001; P00003392; P00000002; P00000003;
```